# Is there a way to get information such as followers, likes and posts of a Facebook page by its url?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, instagram

I am building a project where I scrape websites such as online stores in search for their social media links in order to get insights about the social presence of the given web store. I get the instagram links and facebook links. I now want to get the mentioned information about these public pages. Of course Meta pages are filled with defenses against web scraping and so I wanted to know if there is a way to get this info in a compliant way. I have seen the graph api but it is made for integrations of the social medias in your apps and I don't want any integration. I am just looking for public information.

Comment: There is no other _allowed_ way, than to do this via the relevant APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's API policies do not allow scraping public pages without a proper app review process and access token. Hence, using Facebook's Graph API would be the most compliant way to get public information.

However, if you do not want to integrate with Facebook's API, you can use web scraping techniques to extract public information from Facebook pages. It's important to note that scraping data from Facebook pages without their consent may violate their terms of service and can lead to legal consequences.

If you decide to proceed with web scraping, you can use tools like BeautifulSoup or Scrapy to scrape the Facebook page's HTML code and extract information such as the number of likes and followers. Keep in mind that Facebook frequently updates its website, so your scraping code may need to be updated as well to accommodate these changes.